# Spherical panorama viewer (no Flash, no HTML5)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, web

At the moment I'm supporting an ongoing "virtual reality" project wherein we make use of equirectangulars to create pano cubes. We then take those cube faces and throw them in ActionScript to interact with them in-browser, panning around on both axes to get the spherical panorama.

Now, I want to do this *without* the need for Flash/ActionScript. The problem is, it can't be in HTML5 either. It has to work in -- ugh -- IE9 (I work for a defense contractor). I've found great solutions that suit all of my needs... but it's in HTML5. Any direction I can be pointed in for implementing something like this?

Comment: This is almost certainly too broad a question for SO. IE9 supports both SVG and canvas, so you might see if either of those will suit your purposes.

Comment: No Flash and no HTML5... so you want to use a Java applet? Silverlight?

Comment: no Flash, no HTML5, no spherical panorama.